# make4ht is removing blank lines from verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim, html, make4ht

My LaTeX code file `foo.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Demo}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Foo

Bar

Baz
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Here is how I convert it to HTML using `make4ht`:

```
$ make4ht foo.tex
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo.tex
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

Here is how `foo.html` looks:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='foo.css' /> 
<meta content='foo.tex' name='src' /> 
</head><body>

   <pre id='verbatim-1' class='verbatim'>
Foo
Bar
Baz
</pre>
<!-- l. 11 --><p class='nopar'> </p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

The blank lines in `verbatim` environment have been removed in the HTML output. As a result the output looks different from what it would look if I had compiled the `.tex` file to a `.pdf`.

Is there a way to prevent `make4ht` from removing blank lines in `verbatim` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've introduced this bug recently when I fixed another bug. I will fix it in TeX4ht immediately. Meanwhile, you can use the following configuration file, `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{verbatim}
{\HCode{}}
{\csname a:sp\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Configure{verbatim}` takes two parameters, the first one is code inserted at each line break, the second is a space character. `\csname a:sp\endcsname` inserts non breaking space, which is necessary for correct indenting. `\HCode{}` doesn't insert anything, but it forces `tex4ht` to insert line breaks at the correct places.

This was the HTML code before the change:

```
   <pre id='verbatim-1' class='verbatim'>
Foo
Bar 
Baz
</pre>
```

You can see that the linebreaks at the blank lines are missing.

Now compile your file with the configuration file:

```
make4ht -m draft -c myconfig.cfg filename.tex
```

You will get a correct HTML:

```
   <pre id='verbatim-1' class='verbatim'>
Foo

Bar

Baz
</pre>
```

Which is rendered like this:

[image]